# Azure C# function called by Logic App via HTTP trigger - need to reference a Blob filename through input bindings

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I've created an Azure function in C# to read an .xlsx spreadsheet (via ExcelDataReader) and output a formatted xml file (using XMLWriter). The HTTP-triggered function is working perfectly at the moment, but I've now been told that the disk paths I've been reading/writing my files to won't be available for much longer as our on premise data gateway is going to be abandoned, apparently. So, my function will now have to use blob storage for both input and output.

My processing starts in a Logic Apps workflow, all triggered as an email hits the inbox of a shared account. Any relevant .xlsx attachment is saved into blob storage with the current Logic App run-number used as the file body.

I've built a JSON formatted binding record in the Logic App and passed this to the function in the hope I can pick it up in the declarative code for the Bindings e.g

```
{
    public static class Excel2XML
    {
        [FunctionName("Excel2XML")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Blob({blobName}, FileAccess.Read, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream inputStream,
            [Blob("parked/{sys.utcnow}.xml", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")Stream outputStream,
```

Obviously {blobName} is the value I'm looking to read from the bindings in the first blob declaration - the second blob declaration is for the xml output, which I've given a dateTime body (at least for the time being).

I've read up on LOADS of ways to take this value into the function, and I thought I'd stick with the standard binding solution in the hope of getting that working (I'd like to get the bindings for the input and output streams settled in the declarative stuff at the start of the program if possible). I'd really like to know how everyone else is doing this (successfully). TIA for advice offered.

Comment: I don't see a class that takes your JSON in your method signature. I expect you need a class that has a public property named `blobName`  and that class needs to be an input argument on your Run method. It doesn't need any other annotation

Comment: Thanks rene. So, you're saying I need to build a json record in the request body and reference that structure in the Run method? Then I can refer directly to an element of the Json record in the declaration for the blob?

Comment: Yeah, I think that is how it is supposed to work. At least that is how I interpret https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads as they have a `BlobInfo info` as argument on their Run method.

Comment: I think this pretty much confirms your advice, rene, and it only took me a further half an hour of fumbling and bungling to build the working run method :D https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/azure-functions-binding-to-a-property/

Comment: If you'd care to post your comment as a Solution I'll mark it answered.

Comment: Wouldn't I be repeating what Hury Shen wrote in their Answer? You better accept that then.

Comment: I think Hury Shen endorsed **your** answer and added a suggestion about blob storage connectors. No matter. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rene mentioned in comments, you can add a class which contains a property named `blobName` and imitate [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads) to implement your requirement.

Apart from this, since you use logic app, you can also use [blob storage connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage) of logic app to get the blob content or write to the blob content.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I need the function to be http triggered because of the linear nature of my workflow - there are things done prior to feeding into the function that are worked back into the processing later, so the blob trigger won't work.